# How should I use the callback to get the desired outcome?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, callback, settimeout

Hello there I am getting the desired result when am using promise but how should I implement it with callback when am returning something from the function.

result with promise

```
const first = () => {
    return ("I am first");
}

const second = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        resolve("I am second");
      },1000);
  })
}

const third = () => {
    return("I am third");
}

//using promise

const solve = async () => {
  var f = first();
  console.log(f);
  
  var ans = await second();
  console.log(ans);
  
  var t = third();
  console.log(t);
}

solve();
```

*** using callback ***

```
const first = () => {
    return "I am first";
}

var temp;
const second = (cb) => {
   setTimeout(function() {
    return "I am second";
    temp = cb();
   }, 1000);
}

const third = () => {
   return "I am third";
}


const solve = () => {
    var f  = first();
    console.log(f);
    
    var s = second(third);
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log(s);
      console.log(temp);
    },1100)
}

solve();
```

OUTPUT should be

I am first 
I am second 
I am third

Comment: hi, you can use `then` with callbacks for the success and error conditions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: Could you provide more details on what you are trying to do?

Comment: "*I am getting the desired result when am using promise*" - can you please show that working version for comparison? You can [edit] your question to include formatted code.

Comment: You don't need that global `temp` variable, and your `setTimeout` callback in `second` doesn't really work. It should be `cb("I am second");`, just like where you'd usually call `resolve("I am second");` in a `new Promise`.

Comment: this is the link of what i am trying to do with promise https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3yagchgmj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that global `temp` variable, and your `setTimeout` callback in `second` doesn't really work. It should be `cb("I am second");`, just like where you'd usually call `resolve("I am second");` in a `new Promise`. Then you can receive that value as the parameter of the callback function you're passing to `second(…)`, which should then log it and continue with the remaining steps of the script.

```js
const first = () => {
    return "I am first";
}

const second = (cb) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        cb("I am second");
    }, 1000);
}

const third = () => {
    return "I am third";
}


const solve = () => {
    var f  = first();
    console.log(f);
    
    second((s) => {
        console.log(s);

        const t = third();
        console.log(t);
    });
}

solve();
```

Notice this is not unlike your promise version if you were to use `.then()` instead of `async`/`await` syntax:

```
const solve = () => {
    var f = first();
    console.log(f);
  
    second().then((s) => {
        console.log(s);
  
        var t = third();
        console.log(t);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes am new to this so I was struggling with it I have a better idea now thank you very much